# How did Ezra save Ahsoka in "World Between Worlds"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I just saw the episode "World Between Worlds" of *Star Wars: Rebels* and I am confused as how exactly Ezra saves Ahsoka. So from Vader's point of view, when he is about to strike, does he just see a Stormtrooper's arm reach out from nowhere and then Ahsoka just disappears?

I've read many forums that suggest Ezra has always saved Ahsoka, but what does this mean? Ezra was there with Kanan on Malachor when Ahsoka was fighting Vader, so how does he "always" save her, when "World Between Worlds" happened about 2 years after the fight?

Comment: I expect Ezra was always there to save her the same way that Marty McFly was always there to get his parents to fall in love even when he was also there to get the Sports Almanac from Biff in the second movie. Wibbly-wobbly-timey-wimey *stuff*, to use a phrase from Doctor Who. In other words, since the World Between Worlds is out of time and space, Ezra-from-two-years-later could still save Ahsoka even though Ezra-from-two-years-before was busy escaping.

Comment: So would you say she was alive and going about on her own separate journey between these two years? Because Ahsoka goes back into her timeline in World Between Worlds after the explosion happened, where she then descends further into the temple.

Comment: That'd depend on *when* the portal put her back on Malachor. For Ahsoka, she might've skipped those two years entirely, or the portal might have put her the morning after she fought Vader, or six months after, or three years or more. I don't think we know what happened to her or how her timeline was affected by the portals. Which, by the way, is why I'm commenting and not answering. This is speculation and it might help you rewrite your question at some point or help others answer or leave a starting point if future info comes out.

Comment: She knew that Ezra thought she'd been killed in the fight and thus she was assumed dead for two years, so regardless of when she went back, she'd have known she'd have to stay hidden until after Ezra traveled back to save her for timeline preservation.

Comment: There's a cute comic someone drew of Ahsoka saying "I won't leave you!" and then Ezra's arm reaches out and grabs her.  Vader just stares, and then turns around and says "Well, I'm never telling anyone about this."

The whole "world between worlds" is new SW lore, but it stands to reason that, by the laws of time travel, Ezra was always there to save Ahsoka, and Keith's answer below is a good way to see it - basically, yes, Ahsoka did just vanish.

Answer (score 6):

Vader doesn't necessarily see anything. At the time he swung the floor was collapsing below him, the air was full of dust, there were bright energy discharges, and then he goes through the floor as he swings. Given that we've seen how effortlessly lightsabers slice through people, he could have easily assumed he'd struck and killed her, and her body was lost in the collapse (which, as he's seen limping away later, he clearly had a rough time dealing with). Since she'd been pulled through time, there'd be nothing for Vader to sense; she was just gone, and, he could have assumed, therefore dead.